# Android Retrofit:onNext values needed in other class

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-android

I am using Retrofit with Rx java and I am getting value of authentication token in onNext.Depending on the result of onNext I have to have to post data to server by adding token in the custom header. Should I write all the code in the on next is there any wy to return a value from onNext so when value is avalaible?

```
public String getToken() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl("https://abc.efg.com/")
                        .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                        .build();
                GetTokenInterface service = retrofit.create(GetTokenInterface.class);

                Observable<String> response_call = service.getToken1(setAPI_KEY, setaccesstoken);

                response_call.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted() {

                                System.out.print("Complete");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(Throwable e) {

                                System.out.print("Fail");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onNext(String token) {
                                authentication_token = token; //getting correct value here
                            }
                        });
                return authentication_token;
    }

}
```

Then in another class:

```
generated_token = getToken();
```

but I am getting generated_token null as value is not available Is there any way to get value in it? I have to use this value for posting or Do I need to combine post observable in onNext()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RxJava code is executed asynchronously. For example

```
public class Foo {

    String value = "a";

    public String getFoo() {
        value = "a"; // This executes first
        Observable.just(value + "a")
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
                    public void call(String v) {
                        value = v; // This is called later on IO thread.
                    }
                }); // This creates the observable and schedules execution on IO thread.
        return value; // Return value "a"
    }
}

Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.getFoo(); // Return a
Thread.sleep(100);
foo.getFoo(); // likley Return `aa` (depends upon how long the IO thread take to run)
Thread.sleep(100);
foo,getFoo(); // likley Return `aaa` (depends upon how long the IO thread take to run)
```

If you want to get a value from your method getToken you would return `Observable<String>` if you want you can also save the token in your class as below.

```
public class TokenService {

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://abc.efg.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();
    GetTokenInterface service = retrofit.create(GetTokenInterface.class); // This should be done outside of the method for performance

    String savedToken;

    public Observable<String> refreshToken() {
        return service.getToken1(setAPI_KEY, setaccesstoken)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .doOnNext(new Action1<String() {
                    public void call(String token) {
                        savedToken = token;
                    }
                }) // Do want is needed with token
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    }

    public String getSavedToken() {
        return savedToken;
    }

}
```

Comment: @Developer I updated my examples replacing the lambdas with classes

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate your help